# Algorithm for multiplying arbitrary length polynomials?

Tags: c, polynomial-math

Let's say we represent polynomials as an array of floats, where the degree of each item in the polynomial corresponds to the index in the array (eg. `4.2x^5+x^2-1.4` would be represented as `{-1.4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4.2}`.

My assignment question is to write a method in C that multiples two arbitrary length polynomials and prints out the result (rather than returning it).

Normally, when I ask questions on SO I include what I've attempted so far, but I'm genuinely completely clueless with this one.  This is all I have:

```
void multpoly(float *a, int len_a, float *b, int len_b)
{
    for(i = 0; i < len_result; i++)
    {
        printf(" %.5f, ", product[i]);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Compute the following by hand and post the result: `(ax^2 + bx + c) * (dx^5 + ex^2 + f)`.

Comment: @user3386109 What? How is it connected with the question?

Comment: @python Uhm, let's see, the title says "multiplying arbitrary length polynomials". What do *you* think that means?

Comment: Your representation is incorrect, it should be `{-1.4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4.2}`.

Comment: @user3386109 - thanks, that did help! I can see the 'general case' sort of thing more easily now

Comment: @Wug: thanks; didn't catch that. fixing...

Comment: @user3386109 I think that he want to find a way to write an algorithm which will be able to multiple two polynominals with not fixed length.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11693474/971127

Comment: @user3386109 Ok, I didn't assume that he need more clarification in algorithm, because it's not so hard I guess. If you now see 'general case' you can now create a linked list with with variable and coefficient fields - it will help in keeping eye on powers of multiplied variables, because it is the hardes part of that algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this does what you want:

```
// constraints: 'result' must have space for at least len1 + len2 - 1 elements.
void multpoly(const float *poly1, int len1, const float *poly2, int len2, float *result)
{
    int i, p1i, p2i;
    int len_result = len1 + len2 - 1;

    for (i = 0; i < len_result; i++) result[i] = 0.0;

    for (p1i = 0; p1i < len1; ++p1i)
        for (p2i = 0; p2i < len2; ++p2i)
            result[p1i + p2i] += poly1[p1i] * poly2[p2i];
}
```

[Ideone example of this function](http://ideone.com/wK7R2C)

Comment: Yes that works, but somebody has been faster than you ;)

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a race.

Comment: You r right , but what's the point to add an identical answer! I mean it is already there!! anyways, please edit your answer cuz I can't see where your code is supposed to `prints out the result (rather than returning it).`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    float a[5]={1, 2, 3};
    float b[5]={2, 0, 1};

    printPol(a, b, 3, 3);

}

void printPol(float*a, float*b, int len1, int len2)
{
    int i, j;

    // order of resulting poly is o1+o2
    // o1 = len1 -1
    // o2 = len2 -1
    // length is order + 1 (+1 is the constant number)
    int len = (len1-1)+(len2-1)+1;

    float res[len];
    //initialize 
    for(i=0;i<len; i++) res[i] = 0;


    for(i=0; i<len1; i++)     
        for(j=0; j<len2; j++)
        {
            // mutually multiply all elements

            res[i+j] += a[i]*b[j]; 
        }
    printf("%f ", res[0]);  
    for(i=1;i<len; i++) printf("+%f*x^%d ", res[i], i);


}
```

Comment: "order of resulting poly is o1*o2" No it obviously isn't.