# How to get a specific character in a string

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have a string (an equation or polynomial) and I want to get a specific character in the string. For instance if the users enters:

```
4x^2+3x-9
```

I want to create a node for each term, so in the first node I need to store '4' in its factor and '2' in its power. Following is my code for identifying a node.

```
typedef struct node *ptr;
struct node
{
char sign;
int power;
int factor;
ptr next;
};
typedef ptr poly;
typedef ptr position;
```

and following is the code I've already written for accepting the polynomial from the user:

```
void fillPoly(poly polynomial)
{
system("cls");
char polyn[100];
printf("\t\t\tEnter your polynomial please. Your polynomial should not exceed 7 terms.\n\t\t\t");
scanf("\t\t\t%s",polyn);
position temp;
temp=polynomial;
while (polyn!='\0')
{
    (temp)->next=(position)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
 // Here is the problem

}     
}
```

I don't know how to continue after allocating a node, how would I take the factor and the power and fill them?

Comment: Two problems: First is that you read input from the user *twice*, once with `scanf` and another time with `gets`, the second input overwrites the contents of the character array. The second problem is that to escape special characters in string- or character-literals you should use the *back* slash, like e.g. `'\0'`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've edited it, is it correct now? However, what I'm looking for is a way to get the factor and the powers separately and store them in the node for each term. Is my question clear?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11693474/971127

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet would help u.

```
for(int i=0;i<strlen(poly);i++) {   
// You need only to fetch 4 data members from the string    
// 1 - Sign    
    temp->sign = poly[i++];   
// 2 - Factor    
    temp->factor = poly[i++] - '0' ; // to convert char to int    
// 3 - x ( is ignored in ur case  )    
// 4 - Power
     temp->power =  poly[i++] - '0' ;

 }
```

Input should begin with sign else it will result in wrong answer. This is just a basic code. Further modifications should be done based on the type of input you give. I hope you can do it.